# How to make HTML fit perfectly within a PDF?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pdf, css-grid

Decided to make my resume using HTML and CSS, and I'm having issues with setting the size of the page. I have all of my content wrapped in a div tag that is meant to emulate the size of an A4 PDF. Whenever I go to print my page, it overflows on the right side. I'm learning how to use CSS grid for this project, and I've heard it doesn't always play nice when trying to print.

The A4 paper size for 150 PPI screens is 1240 x 1754, so that's what I set the height and width of the `.page` div to. I'm using the "Save as PDF" setting built into Google Chrome to view the HTML as a PDF

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div class="page">
      <div class="page-top">
         [insert content]
      </div>
      <div class="line">
         <hr>
      </div>
      <div class="page-left-col">
         [insert content]
      </div>
      <div class="page-right-col">
         [insert content]
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.page {
    display: grid;
    width: 1240px;
    height: 1754px;
    grid-template-rows: 20% 1% 79%;
    grid-template-columns: 35% 65%;
    grid-gap: 25px;
    font-family: Rubik;
    font-weight: 400;
    background-color: lightgray;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.page-top {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    margin: 96px 96px 0px 96px;
}

.line {
    grid-column: span 2;
    margin:  0px 96px 0px 96px;
}

.page-left-col {
    margin: 0px 0px 96px 96px;
}

.page-right-col {
    margin: 0px 96px 96px 0px;
}
```

The margins are set to emulate a one inch margin in a normal word document.

I also am using CSS grid display in several other nested divs within my page, if needed, I can provide more context there. But I don't think they should affect anything because they are limited in size by the parent div `.page` and they don't overflow unless I am trying to print the page as a pdf.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a great starting point for HTML-to-print transformations, and PDF is essentially print.

what to do (intermediate)

- remove any size restrictions from page
- wkhtml... has a switch called zoom, 1.5 should be an appropriate
  value to fill the page
- use `page-size: a4;` (default pdf page size)

what to do (the "right" way)

- remove size restrictions from body
- build the background borders (the black ones) with html elements and
  CSS styling
- refrain from defining "width" rules for those. You will only have to
  define a "width" once, all other widths should be set to "auto".
- heights will prove troublesome, because divs are only as high as
  their content requires. But setting height: 100% does not respect
  border and margin sizes.
- that yellow cross could be designed in css too, or a much higher
  resolution png/jpeg
- Use only "real" dimensions. That means do not use pixels, use points,
  inches, or mm. You can use % values, but make sure those are % values
  of real dimensions (that means that at some point a parent element
  has a real dimension)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I set the the body element background to black so I could see the document outline, changed the height and width of .page to 8.26in x 11.69in, and changed all margins to 1 in instead of 96px. This solved my problem when viewing as a PDF.